# how to display selected multiple dropdown values in edit page in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to display selected multiple dropdown values in edit page in CodeIgniter

Values ​​are not displaying in multiple dropdowns on the edit page

this is how to retrieve data in db

```
<?php $assignuserstable = $this->db->get_where('assignuserstable',array('user_id'=>$user_id))->row_array(); ?>

 <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="admin_id"><?php echo get_phrase('Assign User'); ?>
                            <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                        <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="admin_idd[]" id="admin_id"
                            placeholder="Assign User" required multiple>

                            <option value="" hidden><?php echo get_phrase('Select User'); ?></option>
                            <?php
                        $system_usertable = $this->db->get('system_usertable')->result_array();
                        foreach($system_usertable as $row2):
                        ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row2['admin_id'];?>"
                                <?php if($assignuserstable['admin_id'] == $row2['admin_id'])echo 'selected';?>>
                                <?php echo $row2['first_name'];?>
                            </option>
                            <?php
                        endforeach;
                        ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

This is how multiple array is added to the database

model

```
  public function addclientdetails(){

$data['business_name']         = html_escape($this->input->post('business_name'));
$data['legal_name']         = html_escape($this->input->post('legal_name'));
$data['status']         = html_escape($this->input->post('status'));
$data['rating']         = html_escape($this->input->post('rating'));
$data['SU_id'] =html_escape($this->input->post('admin_id'));
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$data['created_at'] =  Date('Y-m-d h:i:s');   
$data['created_by']         = $this->session->userdata('admin_id');

  $this->db->insert('user_table', $data);

    $insertId = $this->db->insert_id
    $admin_idd =html_escape($this->input->post('admin_idd'));
    $result = array();
        foreach($admin_idd AS $key => $val){
             $result[] = array(
              'user_id'   => $insertId,
              'admin_id'   => $_POST['admin_idd'][$key],
              'user_type'   => html_escape($this->input->post('user_type')),
             );
        }    

        $this->db->insert_batch('assignuserstable', $result);  
        $insertId = $this->db->insert_id();
    return  $insertId;
   
}
```

Comment: `if($assignuserstable['admin_id'] == $row2['admin_id'])` - what is `$assignuserstable`? It does not appear to be set at this point?

Comment: <?php
  

    $assignuserstable = $this->db->get_where('assignuserstable',array('user_id'=>$user_id))->row_array();

?>

Comment: That's great - but where is that code? :-) Please edit your question and show that. Is it set somewhere so that the variable is available and working in your view?

Answer (score 0):

it is impossible to identify the problem when you don't share your code. Please share your model and controller too.
At first please echo $system_usertable  and $row2 and check whether there is a data or not.
and your option should looks like this

```
<option value="<?php echo $row2['admin_id'];?>" <?php echo (isset($assignuserstable['admin_id']) && $assignuserstable['admin_id'] == $row2['admin_id'])? 'selected' : NULL; ?>><?php echo $row2['first_name'];?></option>
```